# Finding out what Cache Hibernate is using?

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

Is there any fail safe way to be 100% sure what cache Hibernate is using? i.e is it using EhCache of something else?
Thanks.

Comment: Look how you configured it? There is no second-level cache by default. The one it uses is the one you told it to use.

Comment: Yeah but I want to output something to logfiles in production and catch a misconfiguration quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String cacheIntegrationName = ( (SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory )
    .getSettings()
    .getRegionFactory()
    .getClass()
    .getName();
```

Of course Hibernate already logs "something".  Enable debug logging for the `org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory` logger and look for "Cache region factory : XYZ"

Comment: Good answer.  I'll give this the 50 unless someone can come up with a better one.